# Sum of two max operators

Tags: maxima-minima

Can the sum of two max operators be simplified and written as a single max operator? I have the following forms:
$$\max(a-b,0) + \max(b-a,0)$$
and
$$\max(a-b,0) + \max(c-d,0)$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $a$ and $b$ are reals (including rationals and integers), it's easy to show by distinguishing the cases $a\ge b$ and $a<b$ that
$$\begin{align}
\max(a-b,0) + \max(b-a,0)&\ =\ \max(a-b,\,b-a)\\
&\ =\ \left\lvert\,a-b\,\right\rvert\\
&\ =\ \left\lvert\,b-a\,\right\rvert\\
\end{align}$$

I don't see much simplification possible for the other expression.

Answer (score 0):

The first form can be simplified. If $a>b$, then $a-b>0$ and $b-a<0$. Then $$\max(a-b,0)+\max(b-a,0)=(a-b)+0=a-b$$
Otherwise when $a\le b$, then $a-b\le 0$ and $b-a\ge 0$. Then$$\max(a-b,0)+\max(b-a,0)=0+(b-a)=b-a$$
Hence we have $$\max(a-b,0)+\max(b-a,0)=|a-b|$$
The second form cannot be written as a single max operator in general.